# R: replace NAs with mean of two most contiguous values

Tags: r, replace, mean, na

A data frame:

```
x <- c(3,4,8,10,NA,NA,NA,8,10,10,NA,22)
y <- c(1,6,3,5,NA,44,23,NA,NA,5,34,33)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

x   y
<dbl>   <dbl>
3   1           
4   6           
8   3           
10  5           
NA  NA          
NA  44          
NA  23          
8   NA          
10  NA          
10  5           
NA  34          
22  33
```

I want to replace NA values with the mean of the two most contiguous values. For example `df[5,2]` is `NA` but we can replace it with the mean of 5 and 44:

```
df[5,2] <- (df[4,2]+df[6,2])/2

df[5,2]
[1] 24.5
```

However, this cannot be completed if the contiguous values are also `NA`. Replacing `df[6,1]` with the mean between `df[5,1]` and `df[7,1]` does not work because they are also NA.

What I want to accomplish is making sure the values I'm using to calculate the mean are the two most contiguous and are not `NA`. I created a for loop to create a data frame of the indices where we find `NAs`. Then I created variables representing the indices right next to the `NA` and a test evaluating if they are `NA`. If it is `TRUE` that they are NA the index increases or decreases depending on the position relative to the `NA` index:

```
x <- as.data.frame(which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE))
str(x)

  'data.frame': 7 obs. of  2 variables:
   $ row: int  5 6 7 11 5 8 9
   $ col: int  1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

You will see a dataframe where I have the row and column values for the position of `NAs` in the dataset. Now I attempt to overwrite them:

```
for (i in 1:dim(x)[1]) {

    row <- x[i,1]          # First for loop assigns row and column values using the location of NA
    col <- x[i,2]

    b <- row - 1           # Create a list of the indices that precede the NA
    a <- row + 1           # Create a list of the indices that go after the NA

    ifelse(is.na(df[b[i],col]), b[i]-1, b[i])    # If the value in the list is also an NA, keep looking
    ifelse(is.na(df[a[i],col]), a[i]+1, a[i])

    df[row,col] <- (df[b,col]+df[a,col])/2       # Replace the NA with the mean of values where we could 
                                                 # find integers

}
```

Alas, I am unable to go through all of the NAs. I haven't come up with a better solution and thus turn to better minds. Many thanks!

```
y <- as.data.frame(which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE))
str(y)

'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ row: int  5 6 7 8 9
 $ col: int  1 1 1 2 2
```

Comment: To be sure I understand your question, the fifth, sixth, and seventh values in `df$x` (the three consecutive `NA` values in the first column) should all be 9 ( (10+8)/2 ), right?

Comment: @duckmayr you are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the `zoo::na.locf()` function for this:

```
x <- c(3,4,8,10,NA,NA,NA,8,10,10,NA,22)
y <- c(1,6,3,5,NA,44,23,NA,NA,5,34,33)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

contiguous_mean <- function(vec) {
    return( (zoo::na.locf(vec) + zoo::na.locf(vec, fromLast = TRUE)) / 2 )
}

apply(df, 2, contiguous_mean)

#        x    y
#  [1,]  3  1.0
#  [2,]  4  6.0
#  [3,]  8  3.0
#  [4,] 10  5.0
#  [5,]  9 24.5
#  [6,]  9 44.0
#  [7,]  9 23.0
#  [8,]  8 14.0
#  [9,] 10 14.0
# [10,] 10  5.0
# [11,] 16 34.0
# [12,] 22 33.0
```

Here, "locf" stands for **l**ast **o**bservation **c**arried **f**orward, which replaces `NA` values with the last observed value; with the `fromLast` argument, you can use the closest *previous* observation, or the closest *subsequent* observation. We want the mean of the last previous observed value and the next subsequent observed value, so we just divide by two the sum of the result with `fromLast` as `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

### Update: Leading or trailing `NA`s

G. Grothendieck makes the excellent suggestion to use `na.locf0()` rather than `na.locf()` to make use of the `na.rm = FALSE` default of the former. When the initial or last values are *not* `NA`, the two approaches would be equivalent, but when your columns start or end with `NA`s, then we need `na.locf0()`. Here's a demonstration:

```
z <- c(NA, 1, 2, NA, 3)
contiguous_mean <- function(vec) {
    return( (zoo::na.locf(vec) + zoo::na.locf(vec, fromLast = TRUE)) / 2 )
}
contiguous_mean2 <- function(vec) {
    return( (zoo::na.locf0(vec) + zoo::na.locf0(vec, fromLast = TRUE)) / 2 )
}
## When no leading or trailing NAs, they are equivalent:
all.equal(apply(df, 2, contiguous_mean), apply(df, 2, contiguous_mean2))
# [1] TRUE
## However, when there *are* leading or trailing NAs, the first approach
## causes bad recycling:
contiguous_mean2(z) ## New version
# [1]  NA 1.0 2.0 2.5 3.0
contiguous_mean(z)  ## Old version
# [1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 3.0 2.0
# Warning message:
# In zoo::na.locf(vec) + zoo::na.locf(vec, fromLast = TRUE) :
#   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```